# Github Rest API returning duplicate values

Tags: python, python-requests, github-api

I am trying to create a dataset containing all the repositories and related metadata which were created in 2020 and has Jupyter Notebook as one of their languages.

Since with one call it returns a fixed number of results, I am using a for loop to get 10k repositories but the problem is,all I am getting are the duplicate values. So for example, if the loop runs 2 times and the number of repositories it fetches is 22, only 11 are unique.

I assume it might have to do something with Pagination but I am not able to figure it out.

```
headers = {'Authorization':"Token "+access_token}
repos=[]
for i in range(10): #running only for this range only to check duplicates, in real it would have been larger range
    url=f"https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q='l=jupyter notebook'+created:>2020-01-01+page={i}"
    r=requests.get(url,headers=headers).json() 
    repos.extend(r['items'])
    time.sleep(7)
```

I have tried all the combinations, including keeping url outside the loop and not using page, using `language:` inplace of `l` and so on.

I would really appreciate any help. Thanks!

Comment: Maybe the page numbers start at 1 and not 0? If that were the case, I'd think page 0 and 1 would return the same items. Did you check if that's the case?

Comment: You should use a library like github3.py which takes care of pagination and stuff for you.

Comment: @RandomDavis I just checked it out and it has no effect. Pages start from 1 and I changed i to i+1 for each iteration.

Comment: @tedivm does that handle bulk get requests as well?

Comment: @YashikaSharma so you still get duplicates? Could it be that there are just 11 items and you're trying to access more pages than there are? It seems like you don't know how many pages there are anyway, hence the hardcoded `10`. It seems like you should have some way of figuring out how many pages there are, or at least have some stopping condition when you see that the page contains results that were on previous ones. Assuming, of course, that accessing a higher page number than exists just returns the last valid page's results.

Comment: @RandomDavis when I use this link `https://github.com/search?q=jupyter+notebook+created:%3E2019-12-31&type=Repositories` to directly see number of pages on Github it shows 100. But I read in this(https://hehao98.github.io/posts/2019/04/mining-github-repo/)  blog that the allowed number is 34. I am getting confused here :(.

Answer (score 0):

FYI there is bug in GH Search REST API which returns duplicates when fetching multiple pages of results....

https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/24361#discussioncomment-8212278